# How can I get the limit of a certain infinite product?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

A first look at it suggests the fact the limit is precisely $1$. To check that I tried *Mathematica*, but no output so far. Most probably it converges very slowly. Is there any way to get the limit?

```
Limit[1/n^n Product[(n Sqrt[n] + (n + 1) Sqrt[k])/(Sqrt[n] + Sqrt[k]), {k, 1, n}], 
  n -> Infinity]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think the limit is $1$.

$$\begin{split}
P:=&\frac{1}{n^n}\prod _{k=1}^n \frac{n\sqrt{n}+(n+1)\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{k}}\\
=&\exp\left(
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log\frac{\left(\frac{1}{n}+1\right) \sqrt{\frac{k}{n}}+1}{\sqrt{\frac{k}{n}}+1}
\right)
\end{split}$$

So when $n\to\infty$, by expanding the $\log(\cdots)$ terms againt $1/n$ around $0$, we have a [Riemann sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}P = \exp\left(
\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}+1}\,\mathrm{d}x
\right)$$

```
Exp@Integrate[Sqrt[x]/(1 + Sqrt[x]), {x, 0, 1}]
```

> $4/e$

which is approximately $1.471517765$.

Comparing with the numerical result:

```
With[{n = 10^7}, 
 1/n^n NProduct[(n Sqrt[n] + (n + 1) Sqrt[k])/
                (Sqrt[n] + Sqrt[k]),
               {k, 1, n}]
    ]
```

> $1.471568976960062$

Comment: Indeed. Thank you.

Comment: @Chris'ssis You're welcome!